# Trouble with a switch function menu using structs in C

Tags: c

The program compiles fine however there are a few issues that come up...

1. The calculations will not print out properly.
2. After making a selection the menu will run again automatically without asking for input.
3. Edit employees does not overwrite current employee only adds another to the list.

I am including all my code since I am not sure where the bug is.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
//This is a macro intended for use with the emplyName array.
#define SIZE 20 

//This struct has all the varibles that I will be using in my functions
typedef struct person
{
    char emplyName[SIZE];
    float emplyHours;
    float emplyRate;
    float emplyGross;
    float emplyBase;
    float emplyOvrt;
    float emplyTax;
    float emplyNet;
    float emplyTotal;
}input;


void menu(void);

void editEmployees(input* emply);

void print(input* emply);

void employeeInfo(input* emply);

void calculations(input *emply);

int main(void)
{
    struct person payroll[5] = { 0 };
    int choice = 0, currentEmployee = 0;
    calculations(&payroll);
    do
    {
        menu();
        scanf_s("%c", &choice, 1);
        switch (choice){
        case '1':{
            employeeInfo(&payroll[currentEmployee]);
            currentEmployee;
            break;
        }
        case '2':{
            editEmployees(&payroll[currentEmployee]);
            break;
        }
        case '3':{
            print(&payroll[currentEmployee]);
            break;
        }
        case '4':{
            printAll(payroll);
            break;
        }
        case '0':{
            break;
        }
        default:
            printf("Invalid entry\n");
        }
    } while (choice != 5);
        system("pause");

}

void employeeInfo(input *emply)
 {
        printf("Enter employee name.\n");
        scanf_s("%s", &emply->emplyName,SIZE);
        printf("Enter employee hours.\n");
        scanf_s("%f", &emply->emplyHours);
        printf("Enter Hourly rate.\n");
        scanf_s("%f", &emply->emplyRate);
} 



void calculations(input *emply)/*Write a method that calculates the gross, base and overtime pay, pass by reference.*/
{
    if (emply->emplyHours > 40) {
            emply->emplyOvrt = (emply->emplyHours - 40) * (emply->emplyRate * 1.5);
        }
        emply->emplyGross = (((emply->emplyHours)*(emply->emplyRate)) + emply->emplyOvrt);
        emply->emplyBase = (emply->emplyGross) - (emply->emplyOvrt);
        emply->emplyTax = ((emply->emplyGross)*.2);
        emply->emplyNet = (emply->emplyGross) - (emply->emplyTax);
        emply->emplyTotal += emply->emplyGross;



}


void print(input *employees)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        printf("Employee Name:%s\n", employees[i].emplyName);
        printf("Hours Worked:%.2f\n ", employees[i].emplyHours);
        printf("Hourly Rate:%.2f\n", employees[i].emplyRate);
        printf("Gross Pay:%.2f\n", employees[i].emplyGross);
        printf("Base Pay:%.2f\n", employees[i].emplyBase);
        printf("Overtime Pay:%.2f\n", employees[i].emplyOvrt);
        printf("Taxes Paid:%.2f\n", employees[i].emplyTax);
        printf("Net Pay:%.2f\n", employees[i].emplyNet);
    }
    printf("Total paid to all employees : %.2f\n", employees[i].emplyTotal);
}

void printAll(input *emply)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(emply->emplyName[i], "-1") == 0){ 
            break;
        }
        printf("Employee Name:%s\n", emply[i].emplyName);
        printf("Hours Worked:%.2f\n ", emply[i].emplyHours);
        printf("Hourly Rate:%.2f\n", emply[i].emplyRate);
        printf("Gross Pay:%.2f\n", emply[i].emplyGross);
        printf("Base Pay:%.2f\n", emply[i].emplyBase);
        printf("Overtime Pay:%.2f\n", emply[i].emplyOvrt);
        printf("Taxes Paid:%.2f\n", emply[i].emplyTax);
        printf("Net Pay:%.2f\n", emply[i].emplyNet);
    }
    printf("Total paid to all employees : %.2f\n", emply[i].emplyTotal);
}

void editEmployees(input*emply)
{
    int edit;
    int i;
    printf("which employee would you like to edit?\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        printf("%d.%s\n", i + 1, emply[i].emplyName);
    }
    scanf_s("%d", &edit);
    employeeInfo(&emply[edit]);
}

void menu(void)
{
        printf("Main Menu\n");
        printf("1. Add Employee\n");
        printf("2. Edit Employee\n");
        printf("3. Print Employee\n");
        printf("4. Print All Employees\n");
        printf("0. exit\n");
}
```

Comment: Try running it in the debugger with a breakpoint at the switch. What happens? (Specifically, what is the value of choice?)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Few things:

1. If the menu isn't working properly, it is possible that values are left uninitialized.
2. You should **really** check the return value of `scanf`. Furthermore, you need to clear the input buffer after making a call to `scanf`. `char ch = getchar(); while (ch != EOF && ch != '\n') ch = getchar();`.
3. I don't think you are compiling with warnings; you should. For instance, `currentEmployee;` does absolutely nothing.
4. Inside `editEmployee`, you are passing only a single employee to it. A better way would be to just pass `payroll` **by value**. Arrays will implicitly pass their *elements* by pointer -- if you change the value of one of the array's indices without changing the location the array points to, then that change will be reflected when the program returns to main.
5. You should call calculations ***at the end of*** employeeInfo. Right now, it isn't being called but once.
6. You should properly init `payroll` to actual values; otherwise, the result of calculations is undefined. Also, `calculations(&payroll) is just plain wrong as that *should* pass a pointer-to-array which is obviously not you wanted. (How is the program compiling?)

Here's some editted code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
//This is a macro intended for use with the emplyName array.
#define SIZE 20 

//This struct has all the varibles that I will be using in my functions
typedef struct person
{
    char emplyName[SIZE];
    float emplyHours;
    float emplyRate;
    float emplyGross;
    float emplyBase;
    float emplyOvrt;
    float emplyTax;
    float emplyNet;
    float emplyTotal;
}input;


void menu(void);

void editEmployees(input* emply);
void clear_input(void);
void print(input *employee);
void printAll(input* emply);
void employeeInfo(input* emply);

void calculations(input *emply);

int main(void)
{
    struct person payroll[5] = {
      {
        .emplyName = "-1"
      },
      {
        .emplyName = "-1"
      },
      {
        .emplyName = "-1"
      },
      {
        .emplyName = "-1"
      },
      {
        .emplyName = "-1"
      }
    };
    int choice = 0, currentEmployee = 0;
    int valid = 0;
    do
    {
        do {
          menu();
          valid = scanf_s("%c", &choice, 1);
          clear_input();
        } while (valid != 1);

        switch (choice) {
        case '1':
            employeeInfo(&payroll[currentEmployee]);
            break;
        case '2':
            editEmployees(&payroll[currentEmployee]);
            break;
        case '3':
            print(&payroll[currentEmployee]);
            break;
        case '4':
            printAll(payroll);
            break;
        case '0':
            break;
        default:
            printf("Invalid entry\n");
            break;
        }
    } while (choice != '0');
    system("pause");
    /* Required */ return 0;
}

void clear_input(void) {
  char ch;
  while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF && ch != '\n');
}

void employeeInfo(input *emply)
{
    int valid = 0;
    do {
        printf("Enter employee name.\n");
        valid = scanf_s("%s", &emply->emplyName,SIZE);
        clear_input();
    } while (valid != 1);
    do {
        printf("Enter employee hours.\n");
        valid = scanf_s("%f", &emply->emplyHours);
        clear_input();
    } while (valid != 1);
    do {
        printf("Enter Hourly rate.\n");
        valid = scanf_s("%f", &emply->emplyRate);
        clear_input();
    } while (valid != 1);
    calculations(emply);
}
void calculations(input *emply)
/*Write a method that calculates the gross, base and overtime pay, pass by reference.*/
{
    if (emply->emplyHours > 40) {
        emply->emplyOvrt = (emply->emplyHours - 40) * (emply->emplyRate * 1.5);
    }
    emply->emplyGross = (((emply->emplyHours)*(emply->emplyRate)) + emply->emplyOvrt);
    emply->emplyBase = (emply->emplyGross) - (emply->emplyOvrt);
    emply->emplyTax = ((emply->emplyGross)*.2);
    emply->emplyNet = (emply->emplyGross) - (emply->emplyTax);
    emply->emplyTotal += emply->emplyGross;
}

void print(input *employee) {
    printf("Employee Name:%s\n", employee->emplyName);
    printf("Hours Worked:%.2f\n ", employee->emplyHours);
    printf("Hourly Rate:%.2f\n", employee->emplyRate);
    printf("Gross Pay:%.2f\n", employee->emplyGross);
    printf("Base Pay:%.2f\n", employee->emplyBase);
    printf("Overtime Pay:%.2f\n", employee->emplyOvrt);
    printf("Taxes Paid:%.2f\n", employee->emplyTax);
    printf("Net Pay:%.2f\n", emplyoyee->emplyNet);
    printf("Total paid to employee : %.2f\n", employee->emplyTotal);
}

void printAll(input *emply)
{
    int i;
    float total = 0.0;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        // Array index beside struct name, not member
        if (strcmp(emply[i].emplyName, "-1") == 0){ 
            continue;
        }
        printf("Employee Name:%s\n", emply[i].emplyName);
        printf("Hours Worked:%.2f\n ", emply[i].emplyHours);
        printf("Hourly Rate:%.2f\n", emply[i].emplyRate);
        printf("Gross Pay:%.2f\n", emply[i].emplyGross);
        printf("Base Pay:%.2f\n", emply[i].emplyBase);
        printf("Overtime Pay:%.2f\n", emply[i].emplyOvrt);
        printf("Taxes Paid:%.2f\n", emply[i].emplyTax);
        printf("Net Pay:%.2f\n", emply[i].emplyNet);
        total += emply[i].emplyTotal;
    }
    printf("Total paid to all employees : %.2f\n", total);
}

void editEmployees(input*emply)
{
    int edit;
    int i;
    int valid = 0;
    do {
      printf("which employee would you like to edit?\n");
      for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("%d.%s\n", i + 1, emply[i].emplyName);
      }
      valid = scanf_s("%d", &edit);
      clear_input();
    } while (valid != 1);
    employeeInfo(&emply[edit]);
}

void menu(void)
{
        printf("Main Menu\n");
        printf("1. Add Employee\n");
        printf("2. Edit Employee\n");
        printf("3. Print Employee\n");
        printf("4. Print All Employees\n");
        printf("0. exit\n");
}
```

Comment: Thanks I will make these adjustments if they work I will check your response for the correct answer

Comment: What should be in front of the .name(s) you are setting to "-1"?

Comment: Nothing, this is C11 code and that's what's called a Compound literal. If it isn''t compiling, use `-std=c11` if you are using gcc. Oops, I put names rather than `emplyName`.... I'll fix that later; sorry!

Answer (score -1):

At first

```
struct person payroll[5] = { 0 };
int choice = 0, currentEmployee = 0;
```

here you declare array of 5 structures. And instead of

```
calculations(&payroll);
```

you should use

```
calculations(&payroll[0]);
```

or

```
calculations(payroll);
```

to pass pointer to first element of array.
Variable `currentEmployee` does not changes. This line does nothing

```
currentEmployee;
```

Also, your code contains a number of other problems. You should learn more about pointers and arrays in C.

Comment: What you've stated does not answer any of the OP's questions; it just states a few problems.

Comment: @Isaiah These are important issues that lead to wrong behavior.And may cause OP's problems.